# Visual Basic 2010: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done

Tags: asp.net, .net, oledb

This is my final Graduation Project and I am stuck on this.
Using:

- asp.net 2010
- microsoft access 2007

I have checked the registry and its fine.
Insert is working on other places.

Can anyone please help?

```vb
Public Sub insertreply()
    Dim con1 As New OleDbConnection

    con1.ConnectionString = constr

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim strsql As String

    con1.Open()

    cmd.Connection = con1

    strsql = "Insert Into replyblog("
    strsql &= "repliername"
    strsql &= ",replierprofilepicture"
    strsql &= ",replierreply"
    strsql &= ",replieruniversity"
    strsql &= ",repliertoid"
    strsql &= ",replierid"
    strsql &= ",replierthanks"
    strsql &= ",repliermajor"
    strsql &= ",repliergrad"
    strsql &= ",replierthanked) "
    strsql &= "Values("
    strsql &= "@repliername"
    strsql &= ",@replierprofilepicture"
    strsql &= ",@replierreply"
    strsql &= ",@replieruniversity"
    strsql &= ",@repliertoid"
    strsql &= ",@replierid"
    strsql &= ",@replierthanks"
    strsql &= ",@repliermajor"
    strsql &= ",@repliergrad"
    strsql &= ",@replierthanked)"

    cmd.CommandText = strsql

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@repliername", lblrepliernamen.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@replierprofilepicture", lblreplierpicn.text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@replierreply", tbxinfo.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@replieruniversity", lblreplieruniversityn.text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@repliertoid", Session("QuestID"))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@replierid", lblreplieridn.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@replierthanks", lblreplierthanksn.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@repliermajor", lblrepliermajorn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@repliergrad", lblrepliergradn.text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@replierthanked", "n")
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    con1.Close()
End Sub
```

I am having the error on `cmd.executeNonQuery()`

> Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

Comment: The database fields ReplierToId and ReplierID are of type Text? And if not, the field ReplierID is an Autoincrement field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that there's an issue with your SQL. You're also attempting to put a label without the `Text` property into one of your parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@repliermajor", lblrepliermajorn)
```

...should be...

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@repliermajor", lblrepliermajorn.Text)
```

(Though this may not be the answer).